# Xcode orientation changes every-time before presentViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation

My app supports `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`. And All the ViewControllers  only support `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown` except two ViewControllers. This two ViewControllers support `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`.

The problem is that on iPad everything is perfect, but on iPhone, if each Viewcontroller stays `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`, when I run

```
[currentViewController presentViewController:nextViewController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

currentViewController changes its orientation to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown`, then presents nextViewController1 in `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`.

```
[nextViewController1 presentViewController:nextViewController2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

nextViewController1 changes its orientation to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown`, then presents nextViewController2 in `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`.

Comment: In each viewcontroller you are adding interface orientation rite?

Comment: No, I have a super ViewController named BaseViewController, all the viewController except that two ViewController are inherited from BaseViewController. And inside BaseViewController, I have 'supportedInterfaceOrientations' -> (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown)